# React reference passed to Redux

Tags: react-redux

I am wondering is there any appropriate way from where we can pass component reference to another component by Redux. I know that we can make it with exposed references

```js
function CustomTextInput(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={props.inputRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Parent(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      My input: <CustomTextInput inputRef={props.inputRef} />
    </div>
  );
}


class Grandparent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Parent
        inputRef={el => this.inputElement = el}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

But is there a way we can do it with Redux and also which is the best approach - exposed references or pass reference to redux

Comment: Why do you need to pass the reference? What is the use case?

Comment: Yes, so the case is that I have one parent component and two child components in it. I need the reference of the first child component to be pass to the second child component. Lets say that I need to know the width or height of the first component and I have some interaction with those values in the second component

Comment: Why not use `props` and `state` to maintain that?

Comment: Hi @AjayGaur, yes I can, but when I have more exposed references the code is more unreadable, so I think that it will be better to pass them to the redux

Comment: You shouldn't use ref in react or avoid them because `Avoid using refs for anything that can be done declaratively.` as written in https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html because it breaks the data flow in code. Furthermore you want to expose this to redux, that makes me more uncomfortable. I'll never do this in my code.